# How to select the symbol after Go to symbol in Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to select symbols found with `Go to symbol in Editor...` or `Go to symbol in Workspace...`.

Here is an example :

[image: screenshot of the issue]

The symbol is visually highlighted but when pressing enter the cursor simply moves before the first character of the function.

What I would like to be able to do is easily delete, copy, move, etc, i.e. make a selection.

Comment: there at least is the "expand selection" command if you want a workaround. you could also [raise a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md). If you do, please ping me there with `@starball5` or in the comments here with a link to it.